# We can sort a sequence of values if we have a total order over the elements

Tags: elementary-set-theory, order-theory, well-orders

I'm trying to prove the following theorem:

> Let A be a set and let $\leq_A$ be a partial order over $A$. We say that a sequence $x_1, ..., x_n$ is sorted if $x_1 \leq_a x_2 \leq_a ... \leq_a x_n$. Prove that any subset of $n$ elements of $A$ can be sorted **iff** $A$ is a total order.

I sure think I understand the theorem and intuitively I see that this is true, but I have some difficulties in proving this. I think this is because I'm not sure exactly what I can assume about the sorted sequence. I'm not sure also how to negate the proposition, that the sequence is sorted. So what I tried to do:

1. My first attempt was proving the first direction of implication by contradiction - assume that the sequence is sorted, but $\leq_a$ is not a total order. Then we know that there must be such $x, y \in A $ that $x \nleq_a y$ and $y \nleq_a x$. But this is where I got stuck, I can't come up with a contradiction, because I'm not sure if this $x \nleq_a y$ and $y \nleq_a x$ implies that sequence can't be sorted.
2. The second attempt was a proof by contrapositive, but there is the same issue here. I'm not sure how to negate that the sequence is sorted.

I also know a bit about well-ordering relations, that every well-ordering relation is also a total order. So I think I could prove the first direction of implication if I showed that any subset of the set $A$ has a least element. Similarly, I could probably go this way in my first attempt (proof by contradiction) - show that if there are $x, y$, where $x \nleq_a y$ and $y \nleq_a x$ then any subset of $A$ doesn't have a least/greatest element. But in this case I doubt if it's obvious that the sequence is not sorted.

I'd be grateful for any hints and suggestions, especially about the definition of the sorting in this theorem, what can I assume about this, how to negate this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, to sort $x$ and $y$, you either write $x \le_a y$ or $y \le_a x$.

If you can write neither, $x$ and $y$ cannot be sorted.

This is the gist of the contrapositive proof (which you have shown)

Comment: So you think that the negation of this sorting proposition is exactly the same as the negation of total ordering, right?

Comment: Yes. That is your theorem (though the other direction requires an inductive argument)

Comment: Thank you, but are you sure that we can assume without any additional proofs that if for any $x,y \in A$ neither $x \leq_A y$ nor $y \leq_A x$, then $A$ is not sorted? By the way, if we can assume this, then the other direction can also be proved by contrapositive, $\lnot (A is \ sorted) \implies \lnot(R \ is \ total)$.

Comment: Not (for any) but (there exists some). This is the negation of total ordering: $$\neg (\forall x, y \in A: x \le_a y \lor y \le_a x) \equiv \exists x, y \in A: x\not\le_a y\land y \not\le_a x$$

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry, I thought about existing. I'm afraid that assuming this means automatically that  is a total order, therefore the proof doesn't make any sense.. I'm just trying to imagine a person who theoretically could read my proof and he/she might think why is he assuming this? Why is it so obvious?

Comment: Here we assume that $\le_a$ is not a total ordering, to show that some elements of $A$ cannot be sorted. This is the contrapositive of $\Rightarrow$.

Comment: Thank you, let me think a bit more about this to make sure that I understand this intuitively.

Comment: I think I eventually got what you mean. You just mean that if $\leq_A$ is not a total order, then we have a subset of $A$ (namely $\{x, y\}$), which cannot be sorted. And here we are done with the first direction, right?

Comment: Cannot be sorted. Yes.

Comment: Cool, thank you very much for your help. Next will try to prove the other direction :)