# If $R$ is a total order over set $A$, then all subsets of $A$ can be sorted

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification, order-theory, alternative-proof

I'm working on the proof of this theorem:

> Let A be a set and let $\leq_A$ be a partial order over . We say that a sequence $x_1,...,x_n$ is sorted if $x_1 \leq_A x_2 \leq_A ... \leq_A x_n$. Prove that any subset of $n$ elements of $A$ can be sorted iff $A$ is a total order.

Since this is bidirectional, I need to prove both directions of implication. I've actually already proved the first direction (I asked a [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3813716/we-can-sort-a-sequence-of-values-if-we-have-a-total-order-over-the-elements) about this) - if any subset of $A$ can be sorted, then $\leq_A$ is total. Now I'm trying to prove the second direction, namely if $\leq_A$ is total, then any subset of $A$ can be sorted.

I tried different techniques (direct, contradiction, contrapositive) and the best results I achieved was when I tried to prove by induction, but I can't complete the proof. Here is it:

Assume that $P(n)$ is true iff any set $S \subseteq A$ with $n$ elements can be sorted.

1. Then $P(0)$ is true, since all empty sets are sorted.
2. So assuming that for any $n \in \mathbb{N}$ if $P(n)$ is true, then we prove that $P(n + 1)$ is also true. Consider any set $S \subseteq A$ with exactly $n$ elements and consider element $y \in A$ which is also $y \not\in S$. Since $\leq_A$ is total order we have that $y$ is either the least element in $S \cup \{y\}$, or the greatest element in $S \cup \{y\}$, or there are some $x_l \in S$, where $x_l \leq_A y$, and there are some $x_g \in S$, where $y \leq_A x_g$. In the first and the second cases we are done, because $S \cup \{y\}$ is sorted...

I don't actually know how to prove that the set is also sorted in the third case. Moreover I'm not even sure that my assumptions about the first and the second cases are correct.

Could someone please provide any hints and suggestions for where to go next? Or if you know another way (simplier/without induction) to prove this, please give me a hint.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint**: Try to prove a Lemma: If $\le_A$ is a total order, then for every nonempty finite subset $\{x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n\}\subset A$ there exists a *minimum*, i.e. one $x_i$ such that $x_i\le_A x_1$,  $x_i\le_A x_2$,...,  $x_i\le_A x_n$. Use induction for that.

Then use the Lemma in the inductive step of your overall proof.

Comment: I think I understand what you're getting at. I will try to prove this. Thank you!

Comment: So, I proved this and I think I proved the original lemma. Using you lemma we sure know that all the subsets $A$ with $n + 1$ elements have a *minimum* element. If we remove the minimum from a  subset we will get a subset with $n$ elements which as we know is sorted. If we then return back the minimum we will see that we again get a set with $n + 1$ elements and that the set is sorted, because our minimum is less than all the elements of sorted set with {n} elements. Have I got that right?

Comment: @E.Shcherbo Perfect. (I would just probably say "which as we know *can be* sorted" rather than "which as we know *is* sorted" - but that is about it!)

Comment: thank you very much, your hint was great, it led me to the right direction and the same time made me think.